# how to specify a command in .py file

Tags: python, anaconda, yaml

In Jupyter notebook I can type the command !tabpy to start a service manually

[image]

How do i write this command `!tabpy` in the python.py script file, so that the script runs after environment is built

Below is what i have, which results in error

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
get_ipython().system('tabpy')

2021-02-19T18:12:05.940946708Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-02-19T18:12:05.940961808Z   File "Tabpy_startup.py", line 8, in <module>
2021-02-19T18:12:05.941006819Z     get_ipython().system('tabpy')
**2021-02-19T18:12:05.941018769Z NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined**
```

Comment: Why do you need to launch it from a Python script in the first place? Did you try just printing `tabpy` in the console and hitting enter?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you could try to explicitly import `get_ipython` in your script like this:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
```

This happens implicitly in a Jupyter Notebook.

Side note: I think some of your code is using interactive shell (IPython) specific functionality, which usually isn't suitable for a standalone script. So, if you face further problems, you might want to replace code that uses Jupyter Notebook specific functionality from your script.

Comment: Thanks @Shyam. After importing IPython i'm getting different error "get_ipython().system('tabpy')...AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'system'"